# 404 error: Page not found magento after installation

Tags: php, magento

Good day I've installed a fresh magento. after I've finish the configuration I went to the landing page but it shows 404 error: Page not found page. even when I try to access the admin backend it shows the 404.

the research that I've done says I should replace

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

with

```
Mage::run('default');
```

after I've done that replacement I still get the same 404 error

Comment: have you try to remove cache from var/cache? if not then delete all cache from var/cache

Comment: yes i've deleted everything on the var folder but still it shows the 404